# To add numbers from a file

Tags: python, list, file

Right now, I am trying to include only two arguments and I have been using the code below.

```
for i in d2:
    for j in D1:
        x[j] = d2[i]-D1[j]
        for k in D1:
            if (x[j] == D1[k]):
                break
print d2[i] = D1[j] + x[j]
```

**ERROR**

When I tried to run the code, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 11, in <module>
    x[j] = d2[i]-D1[j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: you are looping over the elements of the lists, not the indices of the list. Indices would take the form `for i in range(len(D2))` but that is generally not very pythonic. I would also look at `itertools.combinations(D1, 2)` to get all  of the pairs of D1 and then you can just check if that is `in D2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the sum of all pairs are in another list (off the top of my head):

```
import itertools as it

D1 = ...
D2 = ...
def my_check(list1, list2):
    for x, y in it.combinations(list1, 2):
        if x+y in list2:
            yield x, y

for x, y in my_check(D1, D2):
    print("{} = {} + {}".format(x+y, x, y))
```

Comment: What if in place of list2 I want to put a number and the numbers in list1 should add up to that number ?

Comment: Change the condition to `if x+y == list2` though you may want to change the variable name in that case.